# How to create a list inside the another list?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a list inside another list. How can I do this?

And how do I retrieve values from the list which is inside another list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question. Do you want something like this?

```
var listOfList = new List<List<int>>(); 
listOfList.Add(new List<int>());
listOfList[0].Add(42);
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer .ya need like this only i need more clear answer

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can clarify this. You are creating a list of `List<int>`. The items in the outer list are `List<int>` objects. In the first line, you create the outer list. In the second line, you create a list of int and add it as one of the items in the outer list. In the third line, you add an integer to the first inner list in the outer list.

Comment: As for me, question is clear, not to elaborated but clear. I would worry if I had such interpretation problems.

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for :) Thank you! +1!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, you mean:

```
List<List<int>> someList = new List<List<int>>();
```

This is a List of Lists

Comment: How about adding to the list? Thanks :)

Comment: Adding a list to the list, or adding elements to a list inside the list ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want strong type lists of for example ints:

```
 var list = new List<List<int>>();
```

of for none strong type lists:

```
new List<List<object>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a custom class to contain your data e.g.

```
public class myContainer<T>
{
    public List<T> contents {get; set;}
}

List<myContainer> x = new List<myContainer>();
```

This has the benefit that if the data type in myContainer changes its isolated from code to get the sub-lists.