# Add a list in a list

Tags: c#, list

Hello and thanks for taking your time!
I have two lists that I want to put together. Can't see how this is possible in my case. Ideas?

This is how my code looks like:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
                userList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID).Take(userCount).ToList();
                userList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID).Take(userCountRandom).ToList();
```

As you can see I want to put userlist in a userlist so i can do both of the functions in the list.
The whole concept is that I want to list out users from my userlist and some of them should be randomed from the database and some should be top 10 registred. and the first list added there is the one that gets latest registred and the other list shuffles the users.

Comment: I think **[it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206160/how-to-create-a-list-inside-the-another-list)** what you are looking for

Comment: You could write `OrderByDescending(user => user.ID)` and get the same result, while having clearer code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to concatenate two lists, you can use the `Concat` extension method of linq. If you don't want duplicates (which can happen in your example) you may want to use `Union`.

In your example, it would be enough to take the max of `userCount` and `userCountRandom` as the lists are ordered by `-user.ID`, therefore the union of this two lists would be equal to the greater of the two.

With your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398339/get-x-random-elements-from-table-in-database-using-linq-or-lamda-in-c-sharp) in mind, I think you want something like

```
userList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID)
                   .Take(userCount)
                   .Union(userList.OrderBy(user => rnd.Next())
                                  .Take(userCountRandom))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: While that will work, there are better ways to shuffle a list, or to select a few random elements from a list.

Comment: @TimS. I've linked the first question when this was the selected answer, just wanted to give a link to the concrete problem/situation of the op.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

```
userList = userList
   .OrderBy(user => -user.ID)
   .Take(userCount)
   .Concat(
userList
   .OrderBy(user => -user.ID)
   .Take(userCountRandom)
  ).ToList();
```

Or if you do not want duplicates use Union:

```
userList = userList
       .OrderBy(user => -user.ID)
       .Take(userCount)
       .Union(
    userList
       .OrderBy(user => -user.ID)
       .Take(userCountRandom)
      ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat one list with the other:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var firstUserList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID).Take(userCount).ToList();
var secondUserList = userList.OrderBy(user => -user.ID).Take(userCountRandom).ToList();

var mergedUserList = firstUserList.Concat(secondUserList);
```